# FineUploader upload gets 401 error and hangs

Tags: ajax, apache, fine-uploader

I'm using FineUploader 5.11.9 "Traditional" to upload pictures to my web server, where a script written using the Perl CGI::Simple module is on the receiving end.  Everything works fine on my internal development system - I use `CGI::Simple::upload()` to get the name of the file and then `CGI::Simple::upload($file,$target)` to magically copy the temp file to where I want it without having to mess around with filehandles (so much easier than with old CGI.pm, once you realise that you need to `use CGI::Simple(-upload)` because upload support is disabled by default!)

But I digress.  Everything is fine on my development system, but on my production system only the first upload works, and then only if I do it soon after loading the webapp page.  All subsequent uploads hang, and when I use the Web Inspector in Safari I see the calls to my CGI script have received a 401 Not Authorized response.

The production server is set with Basic Access Authentication (using `AuthType Basic` etc in a `<Location "/">` section in the Apache `httpd.conf` file (actually `default-ssl.conf` which gets included by it), and Safari is set to remember the username/password, so I'm guessing that my first upload works because the authentication from when the web page loaded is still valid, but when I do another request it has gone stale.

I've had a look on the FineUploader documentation site and can't find anything about Authorization for its AJAX requests.  Google found [FineUploader - add authentication in header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18456789/fineuploader-add-authentication-in-header) which might be the answer, but if it is, how do I find the right value to put in the "Authorization:Basic" header?

Answer (score 0):

To change headers sent with a traditional upload request, use the [`setCustomHeaders` API method](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/methods.html#setCustomHeaders):

```
uploader.setCustomHeaders(
   'Authorization', 'Basic ' + username + ':' + password, 
   fileId
)
```

Comment: I think that should be `'Basic '+btoa(username+':'+password)`, but the real question is where do I get the username and password from?  The entire website is protected using BAA so the user had to enter their username and password in a popup box from the browser before it could load the page containing my JavaScript.  So how do I get the username and password from the browser?